# How to load selenium test suite/case in the Sauce Ondemand?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, saucelabs, ondemand

I need to run my web application in different browsers/platforms via the Jenkins plugin Sauce OnDemand. It is really ridiculous that the official guide of the Sauce Ondemand talks about everything but the most basic thing - how to load test cases/suites. Anyone has idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out. Need to install the Selenium Builder plug in to Jenkins.
Steps:

1. Add the Selenium Builder plugin to Jenkins.
2. Upload test script (html or json) to git repo.
3. In Build, select Invoke Selenium Builder Script.
4. Put script file name there(suppose the script is directly under the workspace folder).
5. Build with the URL of the git repo.

Done.

This solution can only run the script against one browser, not multiple browsers. Trying to figure out how to run multiple.

**Update**

Figured out how to do test on multiple browsers:

Need to install Matrix Project plugin in the Jenkins, create a new job of Multi-configuration Project, select target browsers in Configuration Matrix and Sauce OnDemand Support as well.